# add a line "allow = alaw" before a string "nat = no" in a file sip.conf or any text based file

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, sed

Add a line "allow = alaw" before a string "nat = no" in a file sip.conf or any text based file. If "allow = alaw" already exists before "nat = no" it should not be added.

### File contents:

```
secret =
nat = no
progressinband = yes

allow = ulaw
allow = alaw
nat = no
progressinband = yes

disallow = all
allow = ulaw
nat = no
progressinband = yes
```

### My attempt:

```
awk '/nat = no/ { if(lastLine == "allow = alaw") { print } } { lastLine = $0 }' sip.conf
```

Comment: What have you tried to do to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: I tried awk to grep the last line match, but how to add a line using sed missing and for loop will be required .
```
awk '/nat = no/ {
  if(lastLine == "allow = alaw") {
    print
  }
}

{ lastLine = $0 }' sip.conf

```

Comment: @addijeo Please add your attempts to the question when asking. I have edited your question to include it. Also, please try to provide a *minimal*, complete example with expected input and output. Your sample file is too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
awk -v add="allow = alaw" '/^nat = no$/&&lastLine!=add{print add}{lastLine=$0}1' sip.conf
```

- `-v add="allow = alaw"` sets an variable `add` to awk.
- `/^nat = no$/&&lastLine!=add` checks if current line is exactly "nat = no" and if the last line is not the line we want to add, "allow = alaw". If true,

  - `{print add}` prints the line to be added.
- `{lastLine=$0}` saves the current line value, only in the next cycle it will be used.
- `1` prints the current line.

On a minimal example `sip.conf`:

```
secret =
nat = no
progressinband = yes

allow = ulaw
allow = alaw
nat = no
progressinband = yes

disallow = all
allow = ulaw
nat = no
progressinband = yes
```

```
$ awk -v add="allow = alaw" '/^nat = no$/&&lastLine!=add{print add}{lastLine=$0}1' sip.conf > out
$ mv out sip.conf
$ cat sip.conf
secret =
allow = alaw
nat = no
progressinband = yes

allow = ulaw
allow = alaw
nat = no
progressinband = yes

disallow = all
allow = ulaw
allow = alaw
nat = no
progressinband = yes
```

Comment: Thanks for the help , by this cmd  i'm able to print the desired output but its not getting saved/write in sip.conf.  Please help in it

Comment: using "gawk -i inplace "  able to write into file , but awk version should be 4.1.0 or later.      

gawk -i inplace -v add="allow = alaw" '/nat = no/{if(lastLine!=add){print add}}{lastLine=$0}1'  sip.conf    Thank you  Quasímodo

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, I have made the regex strict. Addijeo, to apply the modifications in the file, the cleanest way is to redirect the output to a temporary file and then overwrite the original file as I have done in the example (see edit). This requires no extension to awk such as the inplace option of GNU awk.

Comment: ```
[general]
allow = ulaw
nat = no

[providertrunk0]
;allow = alaw
nat = no

secret =
nat = no
progressinband = yes

allow = ulaw
allow = alaw
nat = no

```
```
I have one doubt, 
if I want to exclude the whole process for [general]  and [providertrunk0] section,  and apply in whole file
then I am using '/general/,/providertrunk0/{next}' , but its not giving correct output.

My command is as below
' awk -v add="allow = alaw" '/general/,/providertrunk0/{next} /^nat = no$/&&lastLine!=add{print add}{lastLine=$0}1' sip.conf '
```

Comment: @addijeo Sorry I cannot understand it, the comments mangle the line breaks so it is very difficult to read your question. Feel free to post a new question if you are stuck, though!

Comment: okay, I asked a new  question , please see